# json access data not showing properly

Tags: javascript, json

I'm currently processing some json encoded data, but I can't access it properly, this are some tests I did:

**Code fragment 1:**

```
var json = [
{"MarkerId":1,"0":1,"UserId":2147483647,"1":2147483647,"locX":51,"2":51,"LocY":4,"3":4},
{"MarkerId":2,"0":2,"UserId":2147483647,"1":2147483647,"locX":55,"2":55,"LocY":4,"3":4}];
console.log(json[0][0]);
```

outputs:

`1`

**Code fragment 2:**

```
var json2 = getCookie('markers');
console.log(json2[0][0]);
```

outputs:

`[`

**Code fragment 3:**

```
console.log(getCookie('markers'));
```

output:

`[{"MarkerId":1,"0":1,"UserId":2147483647,"1":2147483647,"locX":51,"2":51,"LocY":4,"3":4},{"MarkerId":2,"0":2,"UserId":2147483647,"1":2147483647,"locX":55,"2":55,"LocY":4,"3":4}]`

as you can see when I use the result from test 3 hardcoded I can access it fine, but when I use it only in code i get something diffrent

does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies only store strings. You need to use `JSON.parse()` to convert them back to an object. Also, the contents of `json` isn't JSON but a JAvaScript object (actually, an array).

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse(getCookie('markers') || '[]');
console.log(obj2[0][0]);
```

The `|| '[]'` falls back to an empty array if the cookie is missing since an empty string or `undefined` wouldn't be valid JSON.

Comment: `([])[0][0]` will gives `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: True, in the example it'll fail. But in his actual code he probably won't just blindly access that element.

Answer (score 1):

The `getCookie('markers')` returns string. The native javascript method [JSON.parse(text[, reviver])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) , parse a string as JSON.

```
 var json2 = getCookie('markers');
 if ( typeof(json2 ) == "string" ) {
      json2 = JSON.parse( json2 );  
 }
```

Then try your code ..

Comment: When would you expect the cookie not to be a string? Wouldn't it make more sense to handle empty cookies for this value in a more transparent way?

Comment: @rlemon I know that .. but in question there less informtion about `getCookie` method . Thanks for pointing out that